# How can I remove an item from an array using either javascript or lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

My object is below.  I am using this in angular and have lodash injected into it.  I want to remove the 2nd item using choice2 as what I would pass to match.

```
    $scope.choices = [{ id: 'choice1' }, { id: 'choice2' }, { id: 'choice3'
```

Comment: Just loop though once you find a match splice it off and return.

Comment: If you are passing in the same object reference to the function which removes the item from the array then just splice with indexOf...

Comment: The down-votes to this question is upsetting to see from the SO community. Anytime you wanna learn something new or how a module/frameworks fit into another or anything for that matter you need to see it in its simplest form then after that you can pick it up a lot quicker. And the people that flock to these questions are people that know it well so it seems too simple or that the question is dumb I hate that +rep for question. Thanks for asking it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the remove method of lodash.

```
$scope.choices = [{ id: 'choice1' }, { id: 'choice2' }, { id: 'choice3' }];
_.remove($scope.choices, function(n) {
    return n.id == 'choice2';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_.remove($scope.choices, function(n) {
  return n.id == 'choice2';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla-js, if you don't mind creating a new object, you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
$scope.choices = $scope.choices.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.id !== 'choice2';
});
```

Comment: Would n't be ideal if you want to return after a single match... filter will still run though...

Comment: Yes, I was assuming there could be multiple matches. Otherwise, [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) would be better.

Comment: Looking at the data i thought otherwise. You could just use `some` and splice it off... Need to polyfill findindex or some or whatever for older guys!!

Comment: the problem with using some() in this case is that it would need an outside-callback extra var with closure to get meaning info back (index, val, etc), meaning the probably function cannot be re-used. then there's also the issue with filter of not removing anything but instead duplicating some things.

Answer (score 0):

```
_.filter($scope.choices, function(choices) {
   if(choices.id !== 'choice2') {
      // do something
   }
});
```

this is the programmatic way to do it in case that you want to play with the other choices. You are not going only straight to the point of eliminating one option and just leave it like that, in my case you are eliminating the option and you are telling to the app that after ignore it, then go and do something. If you want to just remove that choice, then go with [xavier hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4913720/xavier-hans) answer

Answer (score 0):

The `_.remove` method augments the given array by removing any matches passed in the second argument.

In this case, pass an object with attribute `id` and value of your var `id`. When iterating over the array of objects, lodash will remove any object that matches that attribute/value pairing.

See example below:

```
$scope.choices = [{ id: 'choice1' }, { id: 'choice2' }, { id: 'choice3' }]
var id = 'choice2';
_.remove($scope.choices, {id: id});
console.log(choices)
```

Comment: Please describe your solution instead of just posting code.